# VS 2015 CTP6 - How to deternine details of Outlines in the code Window

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

I have a package (used to be an Addin) that extends Visual Studio to print the source code of VS projects in color. The current addin also allows the users to choose to output/or not the source in Closed Outlines.

In VS 2015, how does one determine the details (start line, end line, open/closed, etc.) of each Outline in the code window?

Answer (score 2):

Use MEF to import an [`IOutliningManagerService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.outlining.ioutliningmanagerservice.aspx), call `GetOutliningManager()` with your TextView, then use its methods to see the collapsible regions.

Comment: Thank you very much. An example would be really handy PLEASE!

Comment: @JoginderSNahil: I don't have time to write an example right now.  However, the methods should be straightforward.  What are you having trouble with? If you're new to MEF in VS, see http://blog.slaks.net/2013-11-10/extending-visual-studio-part-2-core-concepts/